# Postgres Return jsonb values as jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql, recursion

tl;dr -- is there some way to get values as a jsonb_array from a jsonb object in postgres?

---

Trying to use recursive cte in postgres to flatten an arbitrarily deep tree structure like this:

```
{
  "type": "foo",
  "properties": {...},
  "children": [
    "type": "bar",
    "properties": {...},
    "children": [
      "type": "multivariate",
      "variants": {
        "arbitrary-name": {
          properties: {...},
          children: [...],
        },
        "some-other-name": {
          properties: {...},
          children: [...],
        },
        "another": {
          properties: {...},
          children: [...],
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Generally following [this post](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-navigate-json-trees-in-postgres-using-recursive-ctes/), however I'm stuck at processing the `type: "multivariate"` node where what I *really* want is essentially `jsonb_agg(jsonb_object_values(json_object -> 'variants'))`

### Update:

Sorry, I obviously should have included the query I tried:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree_nodes (id, json_element) AS (
  -- non recursive term
  SELECT
    id, node
  FROM trees

  UNION

  -- recursive term
  SELECT
    id,
    CASE
    WHEN jsonb_typeof(json_element) = 'array'
      THEN jsonb_array_elements(json_element)
    WHEN jsonb_exists(json_element, 'children')
      THEN jsonb_array_elements(json_element -> 'children')
    WHEN jsonb_exists(json_element, 'variants')
      THEN (select jsonb_agg(element.value) from jsonb_each(json_element -> 'variants') as element)
    END AS json_element
  FROM
    tree_nodes
  WHERE
    jsonb_typeof(json_element) = 'array' OR jsonb_typeof(json_element) = 'object'
)

select * from tree_nodes;
```

The schema is just an `id` & a jsonb `node` column

This query gives an error:

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
LINE 16:       THEN jsonb_array_elements(json_element -> 'children')
                    ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

I just want `Object.values(json_element -> 'variants')`

### Update 2:

After reading this all again, I realized this is a problem due to me using a recent version of PostgreSQL (10.3), which apparently no longer allows returning a set from a `CASE` statement, which was kind of the crux of getting this tree-flattening approach to work afaict. There's probably some way to achieve the same thing in recent versions of PostgreSQL but I have no idea how I'd go about doing it.

Comment: Post some schema and a query that you’ve tried if you can.

Comment: You want the three sub elements of 'variants' in an array? Or do want the 'property'/'children' pairs in an array?

Comment: Geez now that I'm looking at it again after eating dinner I realize it's not `variants` causing the problem, it's the array of `children`. Is the example in the article I listed simply not possible in Postgres 10??

Comment: @S-Man I want the nodes flattened so the return would have columns `tree_id` & `node` columns (node being a jsonb object with `type`, `properties` & `children` properties)

Comment: @Steve Please provide a sample of expected output. Which part should be flattened and what happens with the variants?

Comment: Postgres gave you solution to your issue with CASE in the hint. You need to move those function calls to JOINs.

Comment: Because its no really clear to me what should be your result I tried this for the beginning: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=04bbb02d7c1c88168295664428e61ed2 I expanded your test data a little bit with a few more child elements in the array

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I understand the hint is probably helpful however SQL is not my area of expertise and I don't understand how to apply the hint to my dataset

Comment: @S-Man this is so cool! Much simpler than what I had, and _so_ close to what I'm trying to achieve. What I want is to extract the `variants`, same as children (if they're present). This was my attempt, however I couldn't even get variants in a separate column (types should have "leaf1"-"leaf12") https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c351dd3866bae50ad92c968b565c8c51

Comment: I could finalize it for you but please show me the result you expect. If you want the variants, do you want the json objects ir the type names? Should the recursion be repeated for their children? It would be really simple if you could sketch the result.

Comment: @steve I've added a CTE query to my answer below which demonstrates how you can use a multi-stage "pipeline" of CTEs to walk the tree of 'children'; then get each of the the 'variants' values. Splitting the query into chained CTE queries is a much cleaner and more maintainable way to achieve your aim than a `CASE` statement containing the `setof jsonb` functions IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jsonb_each()` in the `FROM` clause together with `jsonb_agg(<jsonb_each_alias>.value)` in the `SELECT`, for example:

```
select
    id,
    jsonb_agg(child.value)
from
    (values
      (101, '{"child":{"a":1,"b":2}}'::jsonb),
      (102, '{"child":{"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}}'::jsonb
    )) as t(id, json_object), -- example table, replace values block with actual tablespec
    jsonb_each(t.json_object->'child') as child
group by t.id
```

You can always chain other `jsonb` functions which return `setof jsonb` (e.g. `jsonb_array_elements`) in the `FROM` if you need to iterate the higher level arrays before the `jsonb_each`; for example:

```
select
    id,
    jsonb_agg(sets.value)
from
    (values
      (101, '{"children":[{"a_key":{"a":1}},{"a_key":{"b":2}}]}'::jsonb),
      (102, '{"children":[{"a_key":{"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}},{"a_key":{"f":6}}]}'::jsonb
    )) as t(id, json_object), -- example table, replace values block with actual tablespec
    jsonb_array_elements(t.json_object->'children') elem,
    jsonb_each(elem->'a_key') as sets
group by t.id;
```

## Update Answer

In answer to your comment and question edit about needing to walk the `'children'` of each tree node and extract the `'variants`'; I would achieve this by splitting the CTE into multiple stages:

```
with recursive
  -- Constant table for demonstration purposes only; remove this and replace below references to "objects" with table name
  objects(id, object) as (values
    (101, '{"children":[{"children":[{"variants":{"aa":11}},{"variants":{"ab":12}}],"variants":{"a":1}},{"variants":{"b":2}}]}'::jsonb),
    (102, '{"children":[{"children":[{"variants":{"cc":33,"cd":34,"ce":35}},{"variants":{"f":36}}],"variants":{"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}},{"variants":{"f":6}}]}'::jsonb)
  ),
  tree_nodes as ( -- Flatten the tree by walking all 'children' and creating a separate record for each root
    -- non-recursive term: get root element
    select
      o.id, o.object as value
    from
      objects o
    union all
    -- recursive term - get JSON object node for each child
    select
      n.id,
      e.value
    from
      tree_nodes n,
      jsonb_array_elements(n.value->'children') e
    where
      jsonb_typeof(n.value->'children') = 'array'
  ),
  variants as (
    select
      n.id,
      v.value
    from
      tree_nodes n,
      jsonb_each(n.value->'variants') v -- expand variants
    where
      jsonb_typeof(n.value->'variants') = 'object'
  )
select
  id,
  jsonb_agg(value)
from
  variants
group by
  id
;
```

This ability of breaking a query up into a "pipeline" of operations is one of my favourite things about CTEs - it makes the query much easier to understand, maintain and debug.

Comment: This is really cool! And kind of blowing my mind... I didn't realize you could chain `jsonb` functions like that in the `FROM` clause. However I don't quite see how to apply this to my problem. Objects in my json have a `children` array or named children in a `variants` hash. I think I kind of want to do (pseudocode) `SELECT id, (json.children || json.variants.values)`

Answer (score 1):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3a3c7f0435ef2350ac112675fa0db2be)

Expanded the test data with more children elements and deeper structure (more nested elements):

```
{
    "type": "foo", 
    "children": [
        {
            "type" : "bar1", 
            "children" : [{
                "type" : "blubb",
                "children" : [{
                    "type" : "multivariate",
                    "variants" : {
                        "blubb_variant1": {
                            "properties" : {
                                "blubb_v1_a" : 100
                            },
                            "children" : ["z", "y"]
                        },
                        "blubb_variant2": {
                            "properties" : {
                                "blubb_v2_a" : 300,
                                "blubb_v2_b" : 4200
                            },
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "type" : "bar2", 
            "children" : [{
                "type" : "multivariate",
                "variants" : {
                    "multivariate_variant1": {
                        "properties" : {
                            "multivariate_v1_a" : 1,
                            "multivariate_v1_b" : 2
                        },
                        "children" : [1,2,3]
                    },
                    "multivariate_variant2": {
                        "properties" : {
                            "multivariate_v2_a" : 3,
                            "multivariate_v2_b" : 42,
                            "multivariate_v2_d" : "fgh"
                        },
                        "children" : [4,5,6]
                    },
                    "multivariate_variant3": {
                        "properties" : {
                            "multivariate_v3_a" : "abc",
                            "multivariate_v3_b" : "def"
                        },
                        "children" : [7,8,9]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "type" : "blah",
                "variants" : {
                    "blah_variant1": {
                        "properties" : {
                            "blah_v1_a" : 1,
                            "blah_v1_b" : 2
                        },
                        "children" : [{
                            "type" : "blah_sub1",
                            "variants" : {
                                "blah_sub1_variant1" : {
                                    "properties" : {
                                        "blah_s1_v1_a" : 12345,
                                        "children" : ["a",1, "bn"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    "blah_variant2": {
                        "properties" : {
                            "blah_v2_a" : 3,
                            "blah_v2_b" : 42,
                            "blah_v2_c" : "fgh"
                        },
                        "children" : [4,5,6]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
variants                 json                                                                                                                                                                                            
-----------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
"multivariate_variant1"  {"children": [1, 2, 3], "properties": {"multivariate_v1_a": 1, "multivariate_v1_b": 2}}                                                                                                         
"multivariate_variant2"  {"children": [4, 5, 6], "properties": {"multivariate_v2_a": 3, "multivariate_v2_b": 42, "multivariate_v2_d": "fgh"}}                                                                            
"multivariate_variant3"  {"children": [7, 8, 9], "properties": {"multivariate_v3_a": "abc", "multivariate_v3_b": "def"}}                                                                                                 
"blah_variant1"          {"children": [{"type": "blah_sub1", "variants": {"blah_sub1_variant1": {"properties": {"children": ["a", 1, "bn"], "blah_s1_v1_a": 12345}}}}], "properties": {"blah_v1_a": 1, "blah_v1_b": 2}}  
"blah_variant2"          {"children": [4, 5, 6], "properties": {"blah_v2_a": 3, "blah_v2_b": 42, "blah_v2_c": "fgh"}}                                                                                                    
"blubb_variant1"         {"children": ["z", "y"], "properties": {"blubb_v1_a": 100}}                                                                                                                                     
"blubb_variant2"         {"children": [], "properties": {"blubb_v2_a": 300, "blubb_v2_b": 4200}}                                                                                                                         
"blah_sub1_variant1"     {"properties": {"children": ["a", 1, "bn"], "blah_s1_v1_a": 12345}}
```

The Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE json_cte(variants, json) AS (
    SELECT NULL::jsonb, json FROM (
        SELECT '{/*FOR TEST DATA SEE ABOVE*/}'::jsonb as json
    )s
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT  
        row_to_json(v)::jsonb -> 'key',                                -- D        
        CASE WHEN v IS NOT NULL THEN row_to_json(v)::jsonb -> 'value' ELSE c END  -- C
    FROM json_cte
         LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(json -> 'children') as c ON TRUE  -- A
         LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(json -> 'variants') as v ON TRUE -- B
)
SELECT * FROM json_cte WHERE variants IS NOT NULL
```

The `WITH RECURSIVE` structure checks elements in a recursive ways. The first `UNION` part is the starting point. The second part is the recursive part where the last calculation is taken for the next step.

A: if in the current JSON a `children` element exists all elements will be expanded into one row per child

B: if the current JSON has an element `variants` all elements will be expanded into a record. Note that in the example one JSON element can either contain a `variants` or a `children` element.

C: if there is a variants element then the expanded record will be converted back into a json. The resulting structure is `{"key" : "name_of_variant", "value" : "json_of_variant"}`. The `value`s will be the JSON for the next recursion (the JSON of the `variants` can have own `children` elements. That's why it works). Otherwise the expanded `children` elements will be the next data

D: if there is a `variants` element then the `key` is printed